# OAuth2RestTemplate TCP connections

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm using a Spring OAuth2RestTemplate with ClientCredentialsResourceDetails to acquire an API authorization token. The authorization server and the API endpoints are hidden behind the same load balancers (LB). We have an issues where the first connection to the API endpoint, after acquiring the token, fails with a 404 error message but subsequent calls to the same API endpoint with the same token are successful. I believe the LB is miss-configured in some way but we've been asked if we could try using separate TCP sessions for the acquisition of the token and then the REST call. Is there a way to get the Spring RestTemplate to do this?

**UPDATE**

Here's how I create and configure the template:

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(
    @Value("${token.uri}") final String tokenUri, 
    @Value("${token.clientId:client}") final String clientId, 
    @Value("${token.secret:secret}") final String clientSecret, 
    @Value("${token.scope:platform}") final String scope, 
    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
{
   ClientCredentialsResourceDetails rd = new 
   ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
   rd.setAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);
   rd.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUri);
   rd.setClientId(clientId);
   rd.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
   rd.setScope(Arrays.asList(scope));

   OAuth2RestTemplate rt = new OAuth2RestTemplate(rd);

   List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = rt.getMessageConverters();
   converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
   rt.setMessageConverters(converters);

   return rt;
}
```

and here's the call to the api:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.set("Connection", "close"); // hmm, gets replace by keep-alive on the token api request!        
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);

ResponseEntity<MyObject[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(
   "http://example.com/api/v1/rest/method", 
   HttpMethod.GET, entity, MyObject[].class);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question. do you also have the url you are getting 404 for?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can share them. But here are examples that closely resemble the endpoints - token: http://example.com/access/token and api: http://example.com/api/v1/rest/method

Comment: I was not interested in the full path, just trying to understand if the app is trying to access some weird url instead of the one it should actually call. Because it doesn't make sense getting 404 instead of a 403 if the issue is about authentication.

Comment: Btw what do you(they) mean by separate TCP sessions. Those should be separate as you need to make 2 isolated rest calls anyway. am I missing smth.?

Comment: I guess they meant HTTP session. To prove something I created a shell script that used 2 separate Curl commands - one to get the token and one to make the api call using the token, and that script worked; that is, no 404.

Comment: But there is no other way as far as I know. How are you sending the token in the header or in the url?

Comment: With Spring when getting the 404, Wireshark shows a "TCP Stream" for both the token and the api call. However, as expected, the script using Curl does not.

Comment: At the same time you mean ?

Comment: the token is a bearer token passed in the header

Comment: Spring app (one Wireshark capture session), then the script (another Wireshark capture session)

Comment: I guess your best shot is to debug that 404 url . I guess something else other than oauth is going on with that call.

Comment: There wasn't any issues in the test lab, but the LBs are different. The problem only occurs on the very first call straight after a call to acquire a new token and all subsequent calls work fine, so the urls shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `Connection` request header with value as `close` while sending your request using resttemplate. This should force the TCP connection to be closed after each request. Not very performant though.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Connection", "close");
```

This is only for the *"but we've been asked if we could try using separate TCP sessions for the acquisition of the token and then the REST call."* part of your question. It will not help resolve your 404 (that does seem to be an LB issue).

UPDATE: Since you're using OAuth2RestTemplate, create a [ClientHttpRequestInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestInterceptor.html) which injects the header.

```
public class ConnectionCloseInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Connection", "close");
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

Use it in your rest template (OAuth2RestTemplate extends RestTemplate so below applies to both) like so (when you create the rest template bean):

```
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> currentInterceptors = new ArrayList<>(restTemplate.getInterceptors()); //Don't want to lose the other interceptors!
currentInterceptors.add(new ConnectionCloseInterceptor()); //Add ours
restTemplate.setInterceptors(currentInterceptors);
```

Comment: Agreed, just a work around until the real issues with the load balancers is found -- I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Didn't work. The POST request to the token uri still had a keep-alive header, but the api GET request had the close header.

Comment: @Matt Forgot about the oauth template. See updated! You need to do that when you create the rest template bean.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either; the header still has "Connection: keep-alive" in the POST to the token service. You may have given me enough already to follow on with. Thanks

Comment: @Matt No problem, please do post an answer if you manage to figure it out. I am curious!

Comment: Will do. I'll work around it now and look later; gut telling me it's down in the JDK somewhere (.e.g. HttpURLConnection), but setting the system property 'http.keepAlive' to false doesn't help either :-(